# Using EF Core how to do a simple join to get one value

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core 3.1.6. I have two model classes:

```
[Table("Stuff")]
public class Stuff
{
    [Key]
    public int StuffId {get;set;}
    public string NameOfStuff {get;set;}
    public int OtherStuffId {get;set;}
    ///this is what I want from the other model
    public string OtherStuffName {get; set;}

    public OtherStuff OtherStuff {get;set;}
}

[Table("OtherStuff")]
public class OtherStuff
{
    [Key]
    public int OtherStuffId {get;set;}
    public string OtherStuffName {get;set;}
  
    public ICollection<Stuff> Stuff {get;set;}
}
```

In my `dbcontext` I have:

```
public DbSet<Stuff> Stuffs {get;set;}
public DbSet<OtherStuff> OtherStuffs {get;set;}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // I'm not really sure what to do here???
    // I've tried this 
    modelBuilder.Entity<Stuff>()
            .HasOne<OtherStuff>(s => s.OtherStuff)
            .WithMany(g => g.Stuff)
            .HasForeignKey(s => s.OtherStuffId);
}
```

This returns an empty data set for "OtherStuff" - not what I am wanting. Any help?

Here is an example of how it's called:

```
var stuff = _context.Stuff.OtherStuffName;  //this is null
var stuffList = _context.Stuff.OtherStuff; //this is null
```

Comment: What is ``RenewalRates``? replace it with ``Stuff``

Comment: @SaeedEsmaeelinejad that was misstype. I've edited that out.

Comment: Your models in fine. Please post how you get stuff data?

Comment: What returns an empty data set for `OtherStuff`? Share the code how you queried for `OtherStuff`.

Comment: @atiyar I put an example of how it's used in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for your main question -

> Using EF Core how to do a simple join to get one value

I would really recommend you to first go through the following documentations to get a clear understanding of how to perform query with `Entity Framework Core` -

- [Querying Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/),
- [Loading of Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager)

As for the two examples you provided -

1. I don't know how you managed to produce `null` with them. Neither of those two line should compile, because you don't have a property named `Stuff` in your `DbContext`. Even if those were typo and you actually meant to write -

```cs
var stuff = _context.Stuffs.OtherStuffName;
var stuffList = _context.Stuffs.OtherStuff;
```

they would still not compile, because `DbSet<Stuff>` doesn't have a property `OtherStuffName` or `OtherStuff`.

2. If you are trying to get `OtherStuffName`, then do either of the following -

```cs
// returns "OtherStuffName" of an "OtherStuff" whose "OtherStuffId" is 3
var name = _context.OtherStuffs
            .Where(p=> p.OtherStuffId == 3)
            .Select(p=> p.OtherStuffName)
            .FirstOrDefault();

// OR,
// returns "OtherStuffName" of the "OtherStuff" which is related to a "Stuff" whose "StuffId" is 3
var name = _context.Stuffs
            .Where(p=> p.StuffId == 3)
            .Select(p=> p.OtherStuff.OtherStuffName)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

3. If you are trying to get a list of `Stuff` with their related `OtherStuff`, then do -

```cs
var stuffList = _context.Stuffs
                .Include(p=> p.OtherStuff)
                .ToList();
```

Some other considerations:

1. Your model definitions are ok, except for the fact the property `Stuff` in `OtherStuff` model should be named `Stuffs` (plural form) because its a collection of `Stuff` entity. Consistent naming matters.
2. Your model configuration is ok, but `.HasOne()` doesn't really need that generic type parameter - `.Hasone(s => s.OtherStuff)` will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still getting used to EFcore. This helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using .Include(x => x.OtherStuff) when you build your query? Relational properties are not loaded if not included in the query using .Include.

Answer (score 0):

For get an entity with its relations you should use `Include` like this:

```
var stuff = _context.Stuff.Include(x=>x.OtherStuff).First();
var otherStuffName=stuff.OtherStuff.OtherStuffName;
```

There is no need to add property `OtherStuffName` in `Stuff` entity because it is in OtherStuff entity.

Comment: so do I need to add anything in the dbcontext OnModelCreating?

Comment: Yes you did right now for define relation between two entities.

Answer (score -1):

You can make the Stuff collection virtual - that will enable lazy loading and EF will load Stuff for you automatically on the fly. Hope that it would work for you :)

```
[Table("OtherStuff")]
public class OtherStuff
{
  public OtherStuff()
  {
      Stuff = new List<Stuff>();
  }

  ...

  public virtual ICollection<Stuff> Stuff {get;set;}
}
```